# adb2c {Context:KMSI} always false

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to return "Remember Me" checkbox selected as a claim in Access_token. Setting this under Sign-In technical profile:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="kmsi" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Context:KMSI}"/>
```

However the value is always returned False. I can see in the b2c-appinsight logs that remember-me was checked:

"Kind": "HandlerResult",
"Content": {
"Result": true,
"Statebag": {
"Complex-API_RESULT": {
"IsCancelled": "False",
"IsErrored": "False",
"IsContinue": "True",
"IsAlternate": "False",
"rememberMe": "true",....

Can someone help, why is Context:KMSI is always returned as false?

Thanks

Comment: Post the entire technical profile and orchestration step it’s called from.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added:

```
<Metadata>
...
<Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
</Metadata>
```

Comment: Yes its there, 
  <Metadata>
            ...
            <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>

If I put any other variables like Context:IPAddress it gets resolved just fine, its only KMSI which is always false.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, today I've ran into the same issue. After some time of digging, it turned out that it seems like Context:KMSI value is resolved at later stage, in the RelyingParty output claims section.
So instead of using Context:KMSI in self asserted technical profile, I just set the value in relying party output claims like so:

```
<RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="CustomSignUpOrSignIn" />
    ...
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
          ...
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ContextKMSI" DefaultValue="{CONTEXT:KMSI}" />
          ...
      </OutputClaims>
```